# When I Deployed django app in Heroku at that time "Compiled Slug Size is too Large" error occurred

Tags: django, git, heroku, django-deployment

I followed the exact steps as mentioned in the [article](https://medium.com/bithubph/how-to-deploy-your-django-applications-on-heroku-8b58fdb09dd0), while deploying my **django** project to **heroku**.

However, I am getting the following **error** for `git push heroku master`:

[git push heroku master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TquxG.jpg)

Please could anyone let me know what could be the possible issue.

**FYI**:

I have the `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`, `runtime.txt` in my project root directory. I am also sure my credentials are correct. Also, I havn't pushed anything to master before and I am the only owner of this app.

My `runtime.txt` has the code: **python: 3.7.9**.

My `Procfile` has the code: **web: gunicorn cardamage.wsgi --log-file -**

My **requirements.txt**:

```
absl-py==0.12.0
astunparse==1.6.3
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
cycler==0.10.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.10
django-heroku==0.3.1
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.28.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.36.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==3.10.0
joblib==1.0.1
Keras==2.4.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.3.1
Markdown==3.3.4
matplotlib==3.4.1
numpy==1.20.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
opt-einsum==3.3.0
pandas==1.1.5
pickle5==0.0.11
Pillow==8.2.0
protobuf==3.15.7
psycopg2==2.8.6
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7.2
scikit-learn==0.24.1
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.11.1
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.4.1
```

Comment: Hi Riya, welcome to StackOverflow, PS: I have the same problem. I think its because of the new git with username and password

Comment: Please do not add images of text - just put the text directly in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum allowed **slug** size (after compression) is **500** MB in [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20allowed%20slug%20size,such%20as%20ls%20and%20du%20.).Your compiled `slug-size` is too large because you use `Tensorflow` module.

`Tensorflow` module is very large (more than **500MB**, the limit for Heroku) because of its **GPU** support. Since Heroku doesn't support **GPU**, it doesn't make sense to install the module with **GPU** support.

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

Simply replace `tensorflow` with `tensorflow-cpu` in your **requirements.py**.

-------------------- OR --------------------

Just replace your `TensorFlow` version to 2.0.0 by doing:

> tensorflow==2.0.0

It has a much lighter weight file and will fit your memory limit. Also, you can use **1.7.0** or **1.5.0** versions.

**Update**:

You can try and reduce your slug size in a number of ways. The easiest is to add a [**`.slugignore`**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore) file to your application to tell the slug compiler to ignore any unnecessary files in your application, such as static assets.

To determine what **`files/folders`** are taking up space in your slug you can inspect slug by starting up a one-off dyno like so:

```
heroku run bash -a <appname>
```

Once in the dyno you can use the **`du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr`** command to show the files and folders in the current directory, ordered by size:
Ex.

```
~ $ du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr
108M    /app
99M     /app/vendor
8.1M    /app/.heroku
448K    /app/lib
292K    /app/spec
8.0K    /app/Gemfile.lock
4.0K    /app/Procfile
4.0K    /app/Gemfile
```

This can be helpful in determining where large files are.

You may also find that [clearing the build cache](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#build-cache) helps reduce the size of the slug.

In your case you used `tensorflow`,`scikit-learn`,`Keras`,etc.. This all libraries are very large.So [**AWS**](https://aws.amazon.com/) is best solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried it, but the slug size is still too big. I guess I will have to dockerize and deploy it or else look for some other cloud platform to deploy.

Comment: @Riya Yes dockerize is best option or AWS platform. see my updated answer.